# Python - проблемы с кодировкой utf-8

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, кодировка

Как заставить пайтон работать с кодировкой utf-8?

Генерируется файл file.pyc (или не генерируется, сам не понял) с win1251 заголовками из utf file.py

Собственно исходный файл. Авось поможет.
Файл кодирован в utf-8 без BOM

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import string
import sys

print ('''Content-type: text/html''')
print ('''
<html>
<head>
<title>Проверка Python</title>
</head>
<body>
Русский текст - Nerusskii text<br>
<ul>''')
```

А в браузер я получаю страничку с хедерами

```
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

и содержимым. (Браузер смотрит в utf-8, а файл то win1251)

```
<html>

<head>
 <title>�������� Python</title>
</head>
<body>
������� ����� - Nerusskii text<br>
<ul>
```

UP (Спустя много лет)
Проблема таки оказалась в Apache.

[Решение нашлось туть](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/352794/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-utf-8-cgi-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-3)

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8    
SetEnv PYTHONIOENCODING utf8
```

Comment: Это как? Чтобы на другие кодировки дико ругался? Или http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Comment: Дико ругался, это конечно интересная идея... Надо будет обмозговать на досуге, но сейчас задача другая.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуй добавить в шапку py

```
## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

И сохранить файл в utf-8.

Comment: Непомогает.

Comment: @Rijen хорошо сказано, чёрт возьми!

А кроме шуток, проблема-то в чём? Или сами должны догадаться, что подразумевается под заданным вопросом?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

1. Собственно в какой программе пишется сам код?
2. Вы пробовали проэксперементировать, например указать в заголовки кодировку как win1251. Так же возможно используемый шрифт в браузере ничего не знает о русских буквах в UTF (помню раньше в windows XP из за таких вот телодвижений, в прочим как и в Висте приходилось в системе жестко указывать шрифт, так как многие приложения не только не знали о русских но и о многих других языках.)
3. Так же стоит попробовать жестко указать функции print о используемой кодировке для строки.
4. Так же не совсем понятно куда выводит ваши сообщения функция print, возможно то что принимает вывод не знает о русских буквах. (когда "система" не знает о русских буквах и получает хотя бы букву в виде набора байт то разбивает ее на две (вспомните СМС, английскими символами написать вы можете больше чем русскими) и мы получаем 2 совершенно самостоятельных символа на выходе, а так как они существую, то естественно в дальнейшей обработке они и идут как 2 совершенно разных символа а не наша русская буква. хотя в вашем случае похоже это не совсем то, так как количество символов здесь не 2 раза больше, но думаю принцип вам понятен.)

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]