# Вывод UTF-8 CGI-скриптом на Python 3

Tags: python, cgi, кодировка, apache, utf-8

Есть CGI-скрипт на Python 3, работающий под Apache 2. Вот он, test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import cgi
import cgitb

cgitb.enable()

print("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8")
print()
print('<H1>Привет, мир!</H1>')
```

Происходит ошибка:

```
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/cgitb.py", line 268, in __call__
    self.handle((etype, evalue, etb))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.3/cgitb.py", line 288, in handle
    self.file.write(doc + '\n')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1452-1457: ordinal not in range(128)

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/cgi-bin/test.py", line 12, in <module>
    print('<H1>\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0435\u0442, \u043c\u0438\u0440!</H1>')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 4-9: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Я много гуглил, находил англоязычные топики с подобной проблемой, но внятного объяснения так и не нашёл. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import sys
import codecs

sys.stdout = codecs.getwriter("utf-8")(sys.stdout.detach())
```

Answer (score 2):

Эмъ... а вы хорошо гуглили?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print 'Привет';
```

Без coding: utf-8 выдает ошибку. [Здесь](http://habrahabr.ru/post/135913/) описано подробнее

UPD: не заметил, что python3... У меня (на 3) ваш код нормально работает )

Может быть [это](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764408/why-python-cgi-fails-on-unicode) вам поможет?

**Обновление**

Нашел [это](http://crustulus.de/cgi-bin/blogstatic.cgi?en=EncodingsatCGIUsingPython3englisch)

У меня в конфиге апача (apache2.conf) прописано:

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8    
SetEnv PYTHONIOENCODING utf8
```

Поэтому и работает. Правда, не знаю насколько это правильно )

Comment: Даже не знаю, какой ответ выбрать. Оба подходят. Рандом дал ответ: наградить @DmitriyM. Надеюсь, никто не обижен)

Comment: @SIvan32, это тов. @Expert виноват ) Я просто комментарий оставлял, а он в ответ зачем-то преобразовал )

Answer (score 0):

Второй ответ мне почему-то приглянулся больше и я стал его проверять:

1. С Python2.7 все работает без изменения `apache2.conf`.
2. Для Python3.5 нужны эти 2 строки в `apache2.conf`.

Мой тестовый скрипт:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cgi, os
print ("Content-type: text/html\n\n")
print ("<H1>Привет из логова ПИТОНА</H1>")
```

Здесь [заметки о настройке CGI](http://adior.ru/index.php/web-server/477-cgi-apache2).