# Как правильно задать кодировку utf-8 в python при генерации файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

Вот исходный код файла-генератора на python. Не могу настроить правильную кодировку при записи в файл, записывает кракозябру

```py
from outfile import outfile_text
from datetime import datetime as dt


def generate_page(head, body):
    page = "<html lang='ru'>" + head + body + "</html>"
    return page


def generate_head(title):
    head = "<meta charset='utf-8'>"+"<title>" + title + "</title>"
    return "<head>" + head + "</head>"


def generate_body(header, paragraphs):
    body = "<h1>" + header + "</h1>"
    for p in paragraphs:
        body += "<p>" + p + "</p>"
    return "<body>" + body + "</body>"


def save_page(title, header, paragraphs, output="index.html"):
    fp = open(output, "w")
    today = dt.now().date()
    page = generate_page(
        head = generate_head(title), 
        body = generate_body(
            header=header, 
            paragraphs=paragraphs
        )
    )
    print(page, file=fp)
    fp.close()


today = dt.now().date()
save_page(
    title = "Заголовок1", 
    header = "Сегодня " + str(today), 
    paragraphs = generate_texts(),
)
```

Пробовал написанное уже здесь решение [Вывод UTF-8 CGI-скриптом на Python 3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/352794/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-utf-8-cgi-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python-3), не помогает. 
Также там пишут, что надо настроить apache. Его можно настроить в openserver или для питона есть свой апач?
Версия python 3.7

Итоговый файл

```html
<html lang='ru'>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>×òî-òî ïðî ãîðîñêîïû</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>×òî äåíü 2019-10-30ãîòîâèò</h1>
    <p>Âå÷åðîì îæèäàéòå íåîæèäàííîãî ïðàçäíèêà. Ïîñëå Îáåäà îæèäàéòå âñòðå÷ ñî ñòàðûìè çíàêîìûìè. Ïåðåä Ñíîì îæèäàéòå íåîæèäàííîãî ïðàçäíèêà.</p>
    <p>Óòðîì áóäüòå îòêðûòû äëÿ ãîñòåé èç çàáûòîãî ïðîøëîãî. Âå÷åðîì îæèäàéòå âñòðå÷ ñî ñòàðûìè çíàêîìûìè. Âå÷åðîì îæèäàéòå íåîæèäàííîãî ïðàçäíèêà.</p>
    <p>Ïîñëå Îáåäà îæèäàéòå ãîñòåé èç çàáûòîãî ïðîøëîãî. Äí¸ì ïðåäîñòåðåãàéòåñü ãîñòåé èç çàáûòîãî ïðîøëîãî. Ïåðåä Ñíîì îæèäàéòå âñòðå÷ ñî ñòàðûìè çíàêîìûìè.</p>
    <p>Ïåðåä Ñíîì îæèäàéòå íåîæèäàííîãî ïðàçäíèêà. Óòðîì îæèäàéòå âñòðå÷ ñî ñòàðûìè çíàêîìûìè. Óòðîì ïðåäîñòåðåãàéòåñü ãîñòåé èç çàáûòîãî ïðîøëîãî.</p>
    <p>Äí¸ì îæèäàéòå íåîæèäàííîãî ïðàçäíèêà. Ïîñëå Îáåäà áóäüòå îòêðûòû äëÿ ïðèÿòíûõ ïåðåìåí. Óòðîì áóäüòå îòêðûòû äëÿ íåîæèäàííîãî ïðàçäíèêà.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: 1) `fp = open(output, "w", encoding="utf-8")`  2) используйте конструкцию `with` для автоматического закрытиях файлах (чтобы не вызывать `fp.close()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В сети есть достаточное количество онлайн сервисов, которые позволяют расшифровать кракозябры в текст и попутно определить кодировки. Это поможет определить, что не так с кодировками. Например, расшифровка текста одного из абзацев позволяет определить, что в кракозябрах отображен исходных текст в кодировки CP1251, зашифрованные кодировкой CP1252. Во избежание подобного, нужно указывать кодировку при открытии файла.

Конкретно в вашем случае, нужно изменить функцию `save_page` следующим образом:

```py
def save_page(title, header, paragraphs, output='index.html'):
    with open(output, mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as fp:
        today = dt.now().date()
        page = generate_page(
            head=generate_head(title),
            body=generate_body(
                header=header,
                paragraphs=paragraphs
            )
        )
        print(page, file=fp)
```

Comment: Проблема кракозябры решена, но если today находится внутри функции, то при компиляции возникает ошибка name 'today' is not defined.Если переменная today находится вне функции, такой проблемы не возникает.

Comment: У вас 2 переменных с одним названием и, судя по всему, проблемы понимания областей видимости этих переменных. Переименуйте их и поймете, какая из них создает проблемы.